# Can't tell what tab I'm on in the profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

This is what I'm seeing on people's profile pages (profile tab):

[image]

I can't tell what tab I'm on. Clicking one switched the view, but doesn't highlight the tab. Can we have tab highlighting back?

Comment: I get the tab I'm viewing rendered as dark text using mobile safari on iOS 8.3. What browser and OS are you seeing the above render?

Comment: @bmike Chrome latest (not dev/canary) on 10.10.3

Comment: This also happens on [android.se], [elu.se], and probably other sites. Previously I wanted to post this on MSE, but after noticing that I can basically read the header instead (as shown by the answer), I decided not.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same on Safari (OS X), you need to look at the title of the list (to the left) to see the selection. I've considered this to be a feature until now :-)

#### "All"

[image]

#### "Questions"

[image]